# Problem finding the average velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity

Problem: A car travels along a straight line for first half time with speed of 40 km/h and second half time with speed 60 km/h. The mean speed of the car is__________.

My answer: 48 km/h

Why?

[image]

However, the answer given in the book is 50 km/h, why? Any help will be really appreciated, thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach, though original, does not yield the average.

There are a few important factors here.

1. The car travels each speed for the same amount of time
2. Those speeds are constant (there is no speeding up/slowing down)

Due to factor #1 being true, we don't have to worry about weighing the average. We can take this average in the simplest way:

`average speed = (40 + 60) / 2`

If the car did 40kph for the first quarter, and then the rest at 60kph, you'd have to take a [weighted average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean).

Answer (score 2):

Why?  Because you did not answer the question as stated...

The question explicitly says that the *time spent at each speed is the same*.

You specifically started by saying the distance at each speed is the same, and along the way you find that *the time at each speed is different*

Different question... Different answer...

The best way to find the average speed is from the definition:$$Average Speed = \frac{Total Distance}{Total Time}$$Assume  say 1 hour at each speed.  Find how far at each speed, total distance, total time, and divide...